# Postgres "reverse count(*)" (unnest?)

Tags: postgresql, count

I'm trying to do what I would call a "reverse count(*)" in PostgreSQL (8.4 +). I want my output to have the exact same number of rows as the number specified in the total column for each letter...

Table 1:

```
letter | total
-------------
a | 3
b | 2
c | 4
d | 1
```

Expected table output:

```
letter
-----
a
a
a
b
b
c
c
c
c
d
```

I am unsure if and how I could use the unnest function here....

Comment: Why do you need to repeat so many strings?

Answer (score 3):

Yes - unnest is what you'll want (once you've got an array of course)

```
richardh=> SELECT array_fill(letter, ARRAY[total]) FROM expand;
 array_fill 
------------
 {a,a,a}
 {b,b}
 {c,c,c,c}
 {d}
(4 rows)    

richardh=> SELECT unnest(array_fill(letter, ARRAY[total])) FROM expand;
 unnest 
--------
 a
 a
 a
 b
 b
 c
 c
 c
 c
 d
(10 rows)
```

Comment: Thank you Richard, with your help I was able to do what I wanted: SELECT UNNEST(array_fill) FROM
 (SELECT array_fill(letter, array[CAST (total AS int)])  from Table1) As Table_output
 ORDER BY 1;

Comment: @Marie-HeleneV. here's [the SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11/2e31f/2) for your solution

Answer (score 1):

Here's solution that uses a tally or numbers table instead of `UNNEST`. It's a fairly cross platform solution in that every database has a solution for creating a numbers table although most not as nice as postgresql.

```
SELECT Letter 
FROM
  table1 
  INNER JOIN  generate_series(1,100) num
  ON table1.total >= num 
ORDER BY Letter
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11/2e31f/9)

I hardcoded the `generate_series` to 100. However as [Clodoado](https://stackoverflow.com/users/131874/clodoaldo) demonstrates you can use `MAX(Total)` in the call to Generate_series

```
SELECT Letter 
FROM
   table1 
   INNER JOIN  
   generate_series(
      1,
      (select max(total) from table1) 
   ) num ON table1.total >= num 
ORDER BY Letter
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11/2e31f/12)

Comment: That would be `(select max(total) from table1)` [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11/2e31f/12)

Comment: @Clodoaldo thanks. I was having trouble getting that to work. I didn't realize adding `()` around the SELECT was the thing to do.